# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined, If span text is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got this error if the span tag text is empty: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` I can't figure out how to fix it. The span tag holds the quantity value in cart, Its function is, if the quantity value is 0 the whole product will be remove. Any idea how to solve this is much appreciated.

```
    <td class="cart-qty" id="<?php echo $id ?>">
        <div id="quantity">
            <input class="addQty btn" type="button" value="+" id="<?php echo $id ?>" />
            <span class="qty" id="<?php echo $id ?>"><?= $qty ?></span>
            <input class="removeQty btn" type="button" value="-" id="<?php echo $id ?>" />
        </div>
    </td>

    <td class="cart-price" id="<?php echo $id ?>">
        <span id="<?php echo $id ?>"><?= $price * $qty ?></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="priceTag" id="<?php echo $id ?>" 
        value="<?php echo $price ?>" /> 
    </td>

     $j(".removeQty").on("click", function(){
            var id = $j(this).attr("id");
            var quantity = $j(this).prev();
            var qty = quantity.text();
            var q = parseInt(qty);
            var row = $j("table").find("[id='" + id + "']");
              var action = "remove";
              if(qty < 2) {
                if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this product?")){
                   row.remove();
                   $j.ajax({
                      url:"http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/action/",
                      method:"POST",
                      data:{product_id:id, action:action},
                      success:function()
                      {
                            
                      }
                   })
                   totalPrice();
                }
                else
                {
                  return false;
                }
              } else {
                 quantity.text(--q);
              }
              subtractPriceByQty(id, qty);
              totalPrice();
        });
        
        function subtractPriceByQty(id, qty) {
            var cart_price_row = $j(".cart-price").find("[id='" + id + "']");
            var cart_price_span = cart_price_row.eq(0)[0];
            var cart_price = Number(cart_price_span.innerHTML);
            var originalPrice = Number(cart_price_row.eq(1).val());
            cart_price_span.innerHTML = parseFloat(cart_price-originalPrice).toFixed(2);
        }
```

Comment: Give the html also please. That will help.

Comment: where is the removeQty, can you put a html for that , also put some example values inplace of php codes. Put a html code that users can run and see the error pls.

Comment: you cannot use same `ids` for mutliple elements .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context it is difficult, but I guess that you need to check that you still have data when you remove the last row. So maybe this fixes your issue:

```
   function subtractPriceByQty(id, qty) {
      var cart_price_row = $j(".cart-price").find("[id='" + id + "']");
      // Check that there is at least one row
      if (cart_price_row.length) {
        var cart_price_span = cart_price_row.eq(0)[0];
        var cart_price = Number(cart_price_span.innerHTML);
        var originalPrice = Number(cart_price_row.eq(1).val());
        cart_price_span.innerHTML = parseFloat(cart_price-originalPrice).toFixed(2);
      } else {
        // Maybe we want to show '0.00' when there are no items
        cart_price_span.innerHTML = '0.00';
  }
```